# Printing with word.application causes error "There is a printer error"

Tags: vb.net, printing, ms-word

When using the following code

```
                Dim oWordApp As Word.Application
                Dim oTargetDoc As Word.Document
                oWordApp = New Word.Application

                Select Case SQLdr("Priority")
                    Case 1
                        oWordApp.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup(Printer:=printPriority1, DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=1)
                    Case 2
                        oWordApp.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup(Printer:=printPriority2, DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=1)
                    Case 3
                        oWordApp.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup(Printer:=printPriority3, DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=1)
                    Case 4
                        oWordApp.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup(Printer:=printPriority4, DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=1)
                    Case 5
                        oWordApp.WordBasic.FilePrintSetup(Printer:=printPriority5, DoNotSetAsSysDefault:=1)
                End Select

                oTargetDoc = oWordApp.Documents.Open(SQLdr("DocumentName") & ".doc")
                oWordApp.PrintOut()
                oWordApp.Documents.Close()
                oWordApp.Quit()
```

The error occures when setting the printer using FilePrintSetup.

If I open word manually and print the document it works fine.

The printers I am using are network printers and looking like "\\mhiav202\HP CM8060 MFP Priority 1" etc.

I can print using Adobe Reader without any issues too.

Comment: The code seems correct. The only thing is the name of the printer. Are you sure that is a complete path in the form \\servername\printername? Also I read something about Option Strict Off required for this kind of code.

Comment: Agree with Steve that it's worth checking the printer names. Try looking at the array [PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.installedprinters.aspx#Y500) and make sure that the printer names you use (whatever is in printPriority1 etc) exists in there.

Comment: I am actually getting the printers from that array, its set by a user interface at the programs startup.

Comment: Oh and Option Strict is already set to Off.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the printername parameter of the fileprintsetup method is case-sensitive. XP and Win7 don't store server\printernames the same way so you may find a problem when upgrading OS